# Как можно сделать обновление программы?

Tags: qt4

Вот написал я программу. Нашел в ней баги или еще что, нужно сделать обновление. Какие есть варианты обновления? Обновление будет храниться на usb флеш. ОС линукс. Пока у меня только одна мысль shell-скриптом, но может есть более лучшее решение?

Comment: https://m.habr.com/ru/post/78094/

Comment: У меня embeded linux.

Comment: Обычно для имбедет устройств обновление осуществляется заменой сооветствующих бинарников. То есть, если есть функция проверки скажем воткнутого USB, то затем проверяется наличие на нем соотвествующих файлов новой версии, ну и затем замена старого кода на новый. Это если грубо, без деталей (в которых живет дьявол, как обычно :) )

Comment: Я наверное сделаю обновление shell-скриптом. А как можно сделать красивый вывод на экран в момент обновления и как соглашаться с обновлением?